# Retrieve config and env variable in vue component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, vue.js

I have a Vue component in my Laravel application.

I want to retrieve a URL that is in a config (or the .env Laravel file) directly in my Vue component, instead of hardcoding it.
In webpack laravel mix I can retrieve my .env variable like this.

`require('dotenv').config()
let proxyUrl = process.env.APP_URL`

But when I want to do this in my app.js, I have a `can't resolve fs` when trying to require dotenv.

What is the best way to have this data available in my Vue components ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue, but placing the variable in blade was not an options for me, also it meant having a variable declare in a blade file and then use in a javascript file which seems a bit unorganized. So if you are in this same position then I think there is a better solution. If you are using Vue you most likely are compiling your files using Laravel mix.

If this is the case you can inject environment variables into Mix, you just need to add the prefix MIX_. So you can add to your .env file a variable like:

```
MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC=http://example.com
```

and then access this variable like this in your javascript file:

```
process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC
```

you can access this anywhere in your pre compile file. You can find this information in the laravel documentation. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables

Comment: I have the same problem, i am getting the error

ReferenceError: process is not defined

Any help?

Answer (score 15):

To access your env variables in a Vue Component file in Laravel, you will need to prefix your variable with **MIX_**.

**In the .env file**

To take your case as an example, if you intend to use *APP_URL* as a variable in your .env file, instead of *APP_URL*, you should use *MIX_APP_URL* like:

```
MIX_APP_URL=http://example.com
```

**In your Vue Component file**

You then access the variable by using the *process.env* object in your script like:

```
process.env.MIX_APP_URL
```

Say today you set a property named proxyUrl and assign the variable as its value, in your script in the .vue file, the code should look like:

```
export default {
  data () {
        return {
          proxyUrl: process.env.MIX_APP_URL,
        },
  }
}
```

After that you should be able to retrieve the property in your vue template as normal like:

```
<template>
    <div>

        //To print the value out
        <p>{{proxyUrl}}</p>

        // To access proxyUrl and bind it to an attribute
        <div :url='proxyUrl'>Example as an attribute</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Here is the [official doc released in Laravel 8.x](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#environment-variables), in case you want to have a look.

Comment: You do need to restart npm run watch after you do this.

Answer (score 4):

> IMPORTANT

You have to reload the bundle for the changes to take effect.

Mine didn't work until I killed the dev bundle and re-ran `npm run watch`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Blade template:

```
let window.something = {{ config('seme_config.something') }}
```

Then just use the variable in JS with:

```
window.something
```

Also, you shouldn't use `env()` helper directly. Extract data from config file only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In my app.js I can't use Blade template.

Comment: where you include the script for your `app.js` (`<script src="app.js"></script>`), on that blade file add `<script>let window.something = {{ config('some_config.something') }}
</script>`

Comment: @Komarzer if you don't like this solution, you can [read a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file) and parse it in `app.js` or use some package that allows you to do that automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to access the the config variables via the typical config('file.option') method in JS frameworks like Vue.

What you CAN do however is pass them as props from your Controller:

```
return Inertia::render('Ticket', ['ticket' => $ticket, 'statusOptions' => config('ticket.options')]);
```

Then in your view catch them:

```
const props = defineProps({
    ticket: Object,
    statusOptions: Array
});
```

Hope this helps!