# How to get a Environment variable in VueJs componets

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Need one help from anyone.

How to get environment variable which is defined under the .env file in Laravel project and i want to access this environment in vuejs component.

```
.env file

SECREAT_KEY=<My secreat key here>
```

And i want to access same variable under the login components

```
export default {
       name: 'login',
        data () {
            return {
                login: {
                    username: '',
                    password: '',
                    grant_type: 'password',
                    client_id: <client id>,
                    client_secret: <SECREAT_KEY I want access here>
                },
                submitted: false
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/49950489/2538636

Comment: You have to reload the bundle for the changes to take effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by creating separate environment variable  prefix with `MIX_`

IN .env file

```
MIX_SECREAT_KEY = 123456789
```

after adding environment variable in .env file now in a vue u can access by `process.env` object for example..

```
  process.env.MIX_SECREAT_KEY
```

> before u access environment variable  first you need to  restart the `watch` task

Comment: This is not working in after the app has been built and deployed, as process.env is available only when run with Webpack / Node development server...?

Answer (score 0):

In your layout file (mostly: app.blade.php) add this before closing head tag:

```
<script>
var APP_NAME = <?php echo json_encode([
  "secret_key" => config('services.secret_key')
]); ?>
</script>
```

In your config/services.php:
add your secret key

```
[
  'secret_key' => env('SECRET_KEY'),
]
```

Now, in your vue file or any js file you can access it like

```
APP_NAME.secret_key
```